# Script Based Authentication using OWASP ZAP Local API

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I have a Zest Authentication Script recorded and I need to add it to a context via OWASP ZAP Local API.

I have set setAuthenticationMethod with the authMethodName=scriptBasedAuthentication but I have not found how to fill in authMethodConfigParams parameter with this kind of authentication.

I would like to know if it is possible using OWASP ZAP Local API using a Zest Authentication script and how to link it to a context.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody help me? Thank you.